# MySQL service is missing

Tags: apt, mysql, mariadb

In my raspberry pi 400, I'm trying to install phpMyAdmin.

I don't know why but I think mysql service is missing.

If I try to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.28-2+b1) ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I try to check the service status, I can't find it...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service mysql status
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Here is an image if you prefer to look here:

[image]

What should I do to reinstall mysql and be able to install phpMyAdmin?

Comment: `sudo systemctl start mysql` if that doesn't work try `sudo mysqld_safe` then use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mariadb-server-10.0` to fix the failed install of MariaDB.

Comment: as I needed a quick fix, I just ended up starting again with a clean image. Installed with Legacy OS and worked perfectly.